# Bind non-const lvalue reference to rvalue

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int &&rfint = 10;
    int &l = rfint;
    std::cout << l << std::endl;
    std::cout << ++l << std::endl;
    std::cout << &l << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Using the above construct, I can directly manipulate the prvalue `10` through the non-const lvalue reference `l`. I can even take address of the prvalue. How does this work? Is it related to [extended lifetime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dcl.init.ref]/5:

> A reference to type “*cv1* `T1`” is initialized by an expression of type “*cv2* `T2`” as follows:
>   ...
>   (5.2.2.2) — If `T1` is a non-class type, a temporary of type “*cv1* `T1`” is created and copy-initialized (8.5)
>   from the initializer expression. The reference is then bound to the temporary.

So `int &&rfint = 10;` creates a temporary, and the reference is bound to it, not to `10` itself.

And yes, the lifetime of that temporary is extended to the lifetime of `rfint`, so you can do whatever you want with it while `rfint` is in scope.